# Migrating of php REST application from Apache to IIS

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, iis, web-config

I have slim framework with .htaccess and front end app which calls api through http protocol.

On **Apache** call is made to **/api/v1/login** - which returns **JSON** response.

On **IIS** when i do the same call, it returns html contents of **/index.php**

apache **.htaccess** is:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [QSA,L]
```

IIS **web.config** ( from Slim framework website ):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="slim" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

What should i do to get proper **JSON** response on **IIS**, instead of **/index.php** contents?

edit

in **IIS Manager | Connection | Handler Mappings** i have

PHP53_via FastCGI as name for *.php , enabled , file or folder , FastCgiModule

PHP55_via FastCGI as name for *.php , enabled , file or folder , FastCgiModule

If my call type is to /api/v1/login - how can i configure it?

==edit

following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32526803/url-rewriting-in-web-config-not-working-for-slim-php-api-in-subdirectory) i received error 500 from api, which means that maybe url rewrite works.

Comment: Did you configure a Module Mapping for *.php in IIS Manager | Connection | Handler Mappings?

Comment: i have fastcgimodule for *.php - do i need to configure * with fastcgimodule in order to api /api/v1/login to work?